# Why are some clergy referred to as "Monsignor" and others not?

Tags: catholicism, clergy

I've heard the title of "Monsignor" used for bishops, archbishops, and even priests. Why are some clergy given this title and others not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Monsignor](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34949) is

> A title of distinction granted by the Pope to numerous prelates. All ecclesiastical dignitaries including archbishops and bishops have a right to this title. (Etym. Italian *monsignore*, literally, my lord.)

Comment: Although note, English speaking Bishops and Archbishops do not routinely use this title